unable to install cocoapods on macbook and latest revision of Ruby
I tried all ways and check all topics related to updating to latest revision of ruby on Mac, and not of them works.
I started by Pod.init command on terminal, the output was the following:
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/version.rb:170:in `initialize': Version value must be a string (TypeError)
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/version.rb:24:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:15:in `new'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:15:in `version'
from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:32:in `<main>'

so, by one of the answer was to remove the the cocoa pods and reinstall it again.
I uninstall it, but now I am facing issue with the installation.
when I put on terminal sudo gem install cocoapods, is show the following:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/logger-1.4.4.gemspec.rz)

Any idea how to proceed, any support will be appreciated

Do you need to install them through Ruby, or Homebrew (at it seems it was) could do the trick too?

I want to install cocoa pods and the latest revision of ruby

This is solved, by using the same command on WRAP. thanks for the developer.

This is solved, by using the same commands which I use on terminal but on WRAP. thanks for the developer
